# In special relativity, what will happen to miserable Schoedinger's cat?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, schroedingers-cat

In special relativity would the life of the Schroedinger's cat be observerd same by two observer?

Two lights emit at the same time from each end of the train heading in the right direction whose gamma is 2 relatively to the observer standing on the ground.

The punching machine is equipped with a sword when the light from the left end arrived to the machine. The machine in the middle swings when the light from the right end arrives to the machine.

For the observer in the train observed that the cat inside in the punching machine dies because two lights arrives at the same time so the machine swings with the sword which has just been equipped by the signal from left light.

For the observer standing on the ground observes that the cat alive because the machine swings with bear hand in that the right light arrives earlier than the left light makes the machine equipped with the sword.

I learned recently that there is no really contraction regardless the terminology of "length contraction". Would the fact that there is no contraction be helpful to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Two lights emit at the same time" according to which frame - the one going with the train or the one on earth?

Comment: Two lights emit at the same time in the train's frame.

Comment: So for the observer in the train the two light signals arrive at a specific point (the punching machine) at the same time?

Comment: Yes for the person in the train sees the two lights arrive at the middle point where the punching machine is.

Comment: If two events occur at the same place and the same time in one frame, then it does so in every frame. Thus the two lights will arrive at the punching machine at the same time also according to a person on the ground.